# Reverting a Git Branch To Make a Clean Pull Request Against the Original Branch Prior to New Code

Tags: git

I am looking for a clean method to make a pull request against a Git branch already code-reviewed prior to `hash_xxx`, but this feature branch is commits ahead of the time of the code review.

I have a git feature branch, `abc`,that is in sync with the upstream `abc` branch. However, the `abc` branch was only reviewed up to a commit in the past prior to hash number `hash_xxx`.

I would like to know the steps to obtain the following criteria:

1. Replicate `abc` onto another new branch, `xyz`, as to exactly match the current `abc` feature branch
2. Back out the changes on `abc` to `hash_xxx` without requiring manual conflict fixing on `xyz`
3. Update both upsteam branches for the coming pull request.

The goal is to make a pull request of `xyz` onto the reverted `abc`.

The issue I would like to avoid is an up-merge needing to occur on `xyz` to be pulled against `abc`. When doing such an up-merge, changes are backed out and these changes have to be made with pasted saved copy and recommitting the whole thing.

What steps can achieve this goal?

Answer (score 0):

> Replicate abc onto another new branch, xyz

```
git checkout abc
git checkout -b xyz
git push -u origin xyz
```

> Back out the changes on abc to hash_xxx

```
git checkout abc
git reset --hard sha1
git push --force
```

That is: if you are the only one working on `abc`. If not, you need to warn other users they will have to reset `abc` to the new `origin/abc` after a fetch.

You can now make a PR from xyz to abc.